# Existe algum vínculo entre o Stack e o Pastebin?

Tags: debate, suporte

Outro dia estava procurando um código e reparei que também estava no Pastebin, pensei que o autor havia postado lá antes, então, só por curiosidade fui ver outra, e também estava lá.

Várias questões estão no pastebin, a princípio só o que vem entre `<code>...</code>` e são só as perguntas. Outro ponto interessante é o horário, sempre anterior ao do Stack, no SO é UTC e no Pastebin CDT.

Existe algum vínculo entre as duas empresas?

---

<sub>**Alguns exemplos de vários:**</sub>

1. [Variável indefinida no CodeIgniter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32788/vari%C3%A1vel-indefinida-no-codeigniter) -> no [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rL2ZU3gy)
2. [Como devo subtrair arrays](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32797/como-devo-subtrair-arrays) -> no [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/LN5jaKLK)
3. [Não consigo carregar dados firebird no Delphi XE2 usando TZQuery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29324/n%C3%A3o-consigo-carregar-dados-firebird-no-delphi-xe2-usando-tzquery) no [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/fv2kabUW)

<sub>**Abaixo estão 2 questões abertas por mim e replicada no pastebin! Todas que possuem `<code>...</code>` vão para lá.**</sub>

1. [Diferenças entre traits e namespace quanto ao carregamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32467/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-traits-e-namespace-quanto-ao-carregamento) no [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Nh1wLg0p)
2. [Redirecionamento: Location vs Refresh](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31910/redirecionamento-location-vs-refresh) no [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vTRu7BaZ)

Comment: Acho que o pastebin é que está "roubando" os códigos pra tentar ganhar alguma visibilidade em mecanismos de pesquisa.

Comment: Pois é, pensei isso, mas o pastebin só aloca código. "Coletando" as perguntas, só vai ter pepino que não funciona... Bugou a cabeça de quem teve essa ideia genial.

Comment: Curiosa descoberta. O timing também é estranho, wtf, quase sincronizado. Pois sim, idéia de jirico.

Comment: Mais interessante que isso seria pesquisar que sites estariam linkando para os respectivos "pastebins".

Comment: Se for 'manual', acho que só os links mais antigos.

Answer (score -1):

Não existem vínculos entre o PasteBin e o Stack Overflow.
O que acontece é que alguns usuários tiram respostas do PasteBin ou colocam as próprias respostas ou dos outros no PasteBin, para não compartilharem links do SO em outros sites de programação.
Até onde vai meu conhecimento, não há nenhum vínculo ou roubo de informações entre os dois.

Comment: Não sei se é isso nesse caso, mas por que não compartilhar links do SO em outros sites? Fiquei curioso.

Comment: Não faz o minimo sentido alguém postar no pastebin uma **pergunta** com código com que não funciona.

Comment: Papa Charlie, pessoas têm motivos diversos para fazer isso, como muitos professores de programação que tiram perguntas daqui do SO para elaborarem aulas. bfavaretto, geralmente fóruns sobre informática e tecnologia proíbem links externos de qualquer espécie.

Comment: @g.carvalho97, adicionei uma questão minha que foi parar no pastebin e eu **não** fiz isso, logo, é o pastebin "coletando" os códigos sem autorização.

Comment: Papa Charlie, como eu disse, pode ser qualquer um que copiou sua pergunta e a possível resposta, não necessariamente o PasteBin. Se isso é um problema a você, por alguém ter copiado sua propriedade sem autorização, isso deve ser encaminhado ao próprio PasteBin, como violação de propriedade intelectual. Ainda assim, creio que a empresa não tem nenhuma intenção de atrair pessoas com perguntas daqui, mas é uma possibilidade entre muitas outras.

Comment: @g.carvalho97 Não me causa problema, era mera curiosidade em saber se era da ciência do stack. A diferença de tempo entre as perguntas do Stack e o conteúdo do Pastebin é minima, ninguém faz manualmente.

Comment: Você acredita mesmo que alguém passaria 24 horas por dia copiando perguntas do SO para colar no Pastebin?

Comment: Papa Charlie, se for assim, pode ser um grupo de pessoas ou até mesmo um programa que filtre perguntas daqui do SO e coloque no PasteBin. Mas, respondendo sua pergunta: Até onde eu sei nenhum site do StackExchange tem vínculo com o PasteBin.

Comment: Ou mesmo um usuário daqui fazendo alguma experiência (já apareceram perguntas relativas a acessar o conteúdo do SOpt programaticamente, via sua API).

Comment: O fato de alguns sites não permitirem links externos é um problema destes sites, é uma limitação que deixa eles em situação vulnerável porque a solução certamente não é copiar conteúdo alheio para o site. O conteúdo daqui pode ser copiado citando a fonte. Se o site proibe fazer isto, ele é um péssimo site, ou incentiva o roubo ou desincentiva postar conteúdo relevante apropriamente

Comment: bigown, existem sites que proíbem a postagem de links para sites de tecnologia, e os usuários recorrem ao PasteBin para poderem colocar o conteúdo sem referenciar o link. Desconheço o motivo, mas acho que é para evitar a divulgação de outros sites. Enfim, essa política existe, e muitos fóruns fazem uso dela.

Comment: Uau! Que beleza de sites devem ser esses, não? Se a melhor "defesa" que eles têm contra os concorrentes é fazer de tudo pra impedir que os usuários descubram que o concorrente existe...

Comment: @mgibsonbr, Método "Coreia do Norte" de programação :)

Comment: @PapaCharlie ao menos a Coréia do Norte e o Stack Overflow tem algo em comum: unicórnios! :)

Comment: @Bacco, Foram eles que descobriram [os unicórnios](http://veja.abril.com.br/noticia/mundo/novo-disparate-da-coreia-do-norte-unicornios-existem) :)

Comment: O SO podia colocar um hidden dentro do code com o link da questão - `<code>See this question in stackoverflow...</code>`. Bye bye estratégia :)

Comment: Interessante... Não sabia dessa. Vou começar a reparar.